# Is it an anti-pattern to use strings as arguments to control function results?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to decide what the best practice is when writing functions that can perform multiple actions. My current solution is to have a string argument that tells the function what to do (eg, `updateTasks('complete selected', data);`).

I realize that I could split this function into multiple functions, but I would be repeating myself a lot that way. My other option would be to use more arguments in the form of boolean statements, but I read to [use fewer arguments](https://www.matheus.ro/2018/01/29/clean-code-avoid-many-arguments-functions/).

## Objectives

- have a small number of arguments
- keep it DRY, or split into multiple functions

## Dataset

```
let data = {
  selectedTasks:[1,3],
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'get milk',
      complete: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'feed cat',
      complete: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'exercise',
      complete: false,
    }
  ]
};
```

## Function

updated based on suggestions by [lealceldeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640649/lealceldeiro)

```
updateTasks = (action, data) => {
  const taskChanges = data.tasks.map(task => {

    const isSelected = data.selectedTasks.indexOf(task.id) > -1;

    if ((action === 'complete selected' && isSelected) || 
    (action === 'complete nonselected' && !isSelected) || 
    (action === 'complete all')) 
      return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: true}); 

    if ((action === 'uncomplete selected' && isSelected) ||
    (action === 'uncomplete nonselected' && !isSelected) ||
    (action === 'uncomplete all')) 
      return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: false}); 

    return task; // keep as is
  });
  return taskChanges;
};
```

## Example of usage

```
updateTasks('complete selected', data);
```

Is this a best practice, or would it be best to split the function up? I want my code to be as DRY and legible as possible.

Comment: Questions asking about best practices are off-topic as they are primarily opinion based. You may have better luck going to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is this a sort of ENUM for current state, that gets serialized to some sort of external database for job handling?

Comment: Just an observation: three `if` with different conditions for `return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: true})` and three `if` with different conditions for `return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: false});`

Comment: How about passing an object like `{complete: true, selected: false}`? Nothing says you have to use multiple parameters to pass multiple booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any anti-pattern.  There is in fact a [command pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html).  However instead of passing a string, how about passing a function to return the complete status.

```
const completeAllAction = () => true; //prev, isSelected parms ignored
const uncompleteAllAction = () => false;
const compleSelectedAction = (prev, isSelected ) =>  isSelected ? true : prev; 
const compleNonSelectedAction = (prev, isSelected ) =>  !isSelected ? true : prev; 
const uncompleSelectedAction = (prev, isSelected ) =>  isSelected ? false : prev; 
const uncompleNonSelectedAction = (prev, isSelected ) =>  !isSelected ? false : prev; 

const updateTasks = (action, data) => {
  const taskChanges = data.tasks.map(task => {
    const isSelected = data.selectedTasks.indexOf(task.id) > -1;
    const newComplete = action(task.complete, isSelected);
    return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: newComplete});
  });
  return taskChanges;
};


updateTasks(completeAllAction, data);
```

I would highly recommend you not omitting the {bloc} after if statements.  See Crockford's [JavaScript the good parts](https://github.com/dwyl/Javascript-the-Good-Parts-notes#chapter9) for details.

You can also use [function composition](https://github.com/getify/Functional-Light-JS/blob/master/manuscript/ch4.md/#chapter-4-composing-functions)  to reduce the parameter count and keep the code dry.

```
const getUpdateTasksFunction = action => {
    //return a function that takes the data object
    return (data) => {
        return data.tasks.map(task => {
            const isSelected = data.selectedTasks.indexOf(task.id) > -1;
            const newComplete = action(task.complete, isSelected);
            return Object.assign({}, task, {complete: newComplete});
        });
    }
}

const uncompleteAll = getUpdateTasksFunction(uncompleteAllAction);
const compleNonSelected = getUpdateTasksFunction(compleNonSelectedAction);
 //  ... continue for each action

//usage with only one param
const newData = uncompleteAll(data);
```